# How do you kill a process for a particular user in .NET (C#)?

Tags: c#, .net, process

I work off of a multi-user Windows Server, and the rdpclip bug bites us all daily.  We usually just open task manager and kill then restart rdpclip, but that's a pain in the butt.  I wrote a powershell script for killing then restarting rdpclip, but no one's using it because it's a script (not to mention the execution policy is restricted for the box).  I'm trying to write a quick and dirty windows app where you click a button to kill rdpclip and restart it.  But I want to restrict it to the current user, and can't find a method for the Process class that does this.  So far, here's what I have:

```
Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();
foreach(Process theprocess in processlist)
{
    if (theprocess.ProcessName == "rdpclip")
    {
      theprocess.Kill();
      Process.Start("rdpclip");
    }
}
```

I'm not certain, but I think that's going to kill all the rdpclip processes.  I'd like to select by user, like my powershell script does:

```
taskkill /fi "username eq $env:username" /im rdpclip.exe
& rdpclip.ex
```

I suppose I could just invoke the powershell script from my executable, but that seems fairly kludgy.

Apologies in advance for any formatting issues, this is my first time here.

UPDATE:  I also need to know how to get the current user and select only those processes.  The WMI solution proposed below doesn't help me get that.

UPDATE2: Ok, I've figured out how to get the current user, but it doesn't match the process user over Remote Desktop.  Anyone know how to get username instead of the SID?

Cheers,
fr0man

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, here's what I ended up doing:

```
           Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();
            bool rdpclipFound = false;

            foreach (Process theprocess in processlist)
            {
                String ProcessUserSID = GetProcessInfoByPID(theprocess.Id);
                String CurrentUser = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.Replace("SERVERNAME\\",""); 

                if (theprocess.ProcessName == "rdpclip" && ProcessUserSID == CurrentUser)
                {
                    theprocess.Kill();
                    rdpclipFound = true;
                }

            }
            Process.Start("rdpclip");
            if (rdpclipFound)
            {
               MessageBox.Show("rdpclip.exe successfully restarted"); }
            else
            {
               MessageBox.Show("rdpclip was not running under your username.  It has been started, please try copying and pasting again.");
            }

            }
```

Comment: I had to replace WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name with WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User.Value for this to work.

Answer (score 9):

Instead of using GetProcessInfoByPID, I just grab the data from StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace KillRDPClip
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();
            foreach (Process theprocess in processlist)
            {
                String ProcessUserSID = theprocess.StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables["USERNAME"];
                String CurrentUser = Environment.UserName;
                if (theprocess.ProcessName.ToLower().ToString() == "rdpclip" && ProcessUserSID == CurrentUser)
                {
                    theprocess.Kill();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the following CodeProject article, it has all the information you need:

> [How To Get Process Owner ID and Current User SID](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/processownersid.aspx)

Comment: Looks good, except I can't get VS to recognized ObjectQuery, even with a Using System.Management.  This is an area I'm wholly unfamiliar with.

Comment: Ah, nevermind.  That's only supported in .NET 2.0 and below.  Fixed now.

Comment: Personally, I would go the Win32/PInvoke route rather than WMI in this case. However, that's just preference, I think the WMI method would work just as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can open cmd in hidden mode and kill the process specific to user. Over here I'm trying to kill Excel process specific to current user:

```
            String CurrentUser = Environment.UserName;
            Process[] allExcelProcesses = Process.GetProcessesByName("excel");
            if (null != allExcelProcesses)
            {
                Process process = new Process();
                ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
                startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
                startInfo.Arguments = "/C TASKKILL /F /FI \"USERNAME eq " + CurrentUser + "\" /IM EXCEL.EXE";
                process.StartInfo = startInfo;
                process.Start();
                process.WaitForExit();
            }
```